# ¿Como puedo ajustar el tamaño de una matriz para que se ajuste al tamaño de mis muestras de entrada?

Tags: python, redes-neuronales

Estoy realizando un TFG sobre redes neuronales pero el tamaño de mis muestras de entrada es diferente con el número de etiquetas que tengo que asignar. ¿Como añado más etiquetas?

Answer (score 0):

No tengo el código pero supongo que con `lista.append([una, fila, más])`, 
o con:

```
for fila in lista:
    fila.append(unas)
    fila.append(columnas)
    fila.append(más)
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.